# Given $a^7=b^5=a^2b=1_G. $ show that $a=b=1_G.$

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is a problem from my algebra book:

Let G be a group and a,b $\in $ G. Suppose that
$$a^7=b^5=a^2b=1_G. $$

Show that $a=b=1_G$.

I know I have to manipulate it somehow and tried doing
$$a^7=a^2b \iff a^5a^2=a^2b \iff a^5=b, $$
and the same for
$$b^5=a^2b \iff bb^4=a^2b \iff b^4=a^2.$$

Then I use the above
$$bb^3=a^2 $$
$$a^5b^3=a^2 \iff a^3b^3=1_G $$
$$a^3b^3=1_G=a^2b.$$
$$ ab^2=1_G=a^2b.$$
Then
$$ab^2=a^2b=1_g \iff b=a=1_G.$$

However, I have no feeling for algebra yet so I'm not sure if this 'solution' is considered correct or if there is a easier way to solve it so I would appreciate some feedback, thanks in advance!

Comment: The second equivalence is not done correctly. Multiply instead $b^5=a^2b$ from the right with $b^{-1}$. Also $a^5b^3=b^4=a^2$. Otherwise it seems OK.

Comment: So $a^5a^2=a^2b$ does not mean that $a^5=b$, because the products are not commutative.

Comment: oh I see, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$G$ is a group, so $\forall g\in G$ $\exists h\in G:gh=hg=1_G$

$$a^2b=1_G \underset{\exists b^{-1}\in G}{\implies} a^2=b^{-1}\implies (a^2)^7=(b^{-1})^7\implies$$ $$(a^7)^2=(b^7)^{-1}\implies 1_G^2=(b^2b^5)^{-1} \underset{b^5=1_G}{\implies}1_G=b^{-2}$$
From Hp we have $b^7=1_G$, so $o(b)|7$ and, since $\forall g\in G$ $o(g^{-1})=o(g)$, from the equivalence $b^{-2}=(b^{-1})^2=1_G$, we have that $o(b^{-1})=o(b)|2$. 
So, $o(b)|2,7\iff o(b)=1\implies b=1_G$.
Do the same thing for $a$ with the Hp that $o(a)|5$ and from the equivalence $a^2b=1_G$, the order of $a$ is forced to be $1$ and we can conclude that $a=b=1_G$.

Comment: I dont now what Hp is though :/

Comment: It means hypothesis

Comment: oh okay, thanks!

Comment: Sorry, we use it a lot at uni.